# Taking inputs on consecutive lines using list comprehension in python

Tags: python, list, user-input

I want to take two lines consecutively as inputs, where the first line is my array and second array are the elements I want to search using binary search.  However, after entering both lines it expects more lines and doesn't work as expected.

```
def my_bin(a, key):
    l = 0
    h = len(a) - 1
    loc = -1
    while(l < h):
        m = l + (h - l) // 2
        if (a[m] == key):
            loc = m
        elif (key < a[m]):
            h = m
        elif(key > a[m]):
            l = m + 1

    return loc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    ktf = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    ktf = ktf[1:]
    a = sorted(a)
    for ele in ktf:
        t = my_bin(a, ele)
        print(t, end=" ")
```

example:
line 1:7 8 6 546 878 98 34 543
line 2: 4 6 7 8 786

outut:
0 1 2 -1

First line is array to be sorted and searched.
Second line has first value as number on values to search which is "4" here and after that the values to be searched in above array.

Comment: Did you mean: `a=[int(x) for x in input()]`? ie without the `.split()`?

Comment: What are you putting as your input values?

Comment: You need to add a `break` after `loc = m`, otherwise the while-loop will never terminate.

Comment: thanks a lot ! That was the problem actually.Finally it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not with the input . The while loop inside your `my_bin` is not terminating as you have only `if and elif` if it doesn't match any of the condition it will be in a non terminating loop.